# How log spring boot jar file exceptions

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, executable-jar

When you create Tomcat embedded **JAR** file and install it on a server, how can access to the Exceptions? Recently my server and process stops suddenly and I do not know what is going on. I checked Windows Event viewer but could not find anything. 
Is there any place that exception writes for example on a file?

Comment: Look into the catalina.out file in your TOMCAT_HOME/logs directory

Comment: @Jens where is TOMCAT_HOME?

Comment: It depends on where you have installed it

Comment: I embedded TomCat with my jar file. So really I do not know where is it.

Comment: search for the file Name on your computer

Comment: @Jens ok I found about 6 folder all in user\AppData\Local\Temp\2 but all have empty folders like work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT and there is no log file or folder.

Comment: Spring Boot has Tomcat running inside it.  You should use some kind of logging (e.g. log4j).  Where it's written to depends on your deployment.  Is there a console or command shell running?  If that hasn't disappeared, look for messages there.

Comment: Check this answer, I think it responds to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939886/869462

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console** and will not
>   write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
>   console output you need to set a **logging.file** or **logging.path** property
>   (for example in your application.properties).

```
java -Dlogging.file=target/my_logfile.log -jar spring_boot_app.jar
or 
java -Dlogging.path=target/logs -jar spring_boot_app.jar
(Will create spring.log file inside target/logs)
```

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output

To make life easier you can use **logback.xml** or **logback-spring.xml**

Following is a sample of **logback.xml**. Include it inside **src/main/resources** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<!-- The FILE and ASYNC appenders are here as examples for a production configuration -->

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>


    <!-- your project package -->
    <logger name="com.test" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- <logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.codahale.metrics" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.sun" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.undertow" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.undertow.websockets.jsr" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="liquibase" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="LiquibaseSchemaResolver" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/> -->

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Above configuration will generate the logs to the the working directory of the JAR file with the names like **logFile.yyyy.MM.dd.log**

Comment: I get the first part and it is works. for better life i want to use second part of your answer. If it is ok just this code with logback.xml named file in resources?

Comment: Yes, I tested it wit the latest spring boot `1.5.6`. It should work. Please replace `com.test` with your project's base package.

Comment: what is the benefit of using logback.xml vs @mike adamenko's answer. I mean simply put 3 lines in properties?

Comment: In the current configuration log files will be produced in the same directory as JAR file. `fileNamePattern` tag can be edited to include a path like `logs/logFile...`. Benefit of `logback.xml` is that it will centralize the logging configuration. you can set can specify the log4j like rolling appender and other configuration here.

Comment: thank to dear Mike Adamenko, your answer is more efficient.

Comment: You're welcome, I just removed the `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` from the `logback.xml`. It seemed unnecessary.

Comment: how can handle which logs be saved? for Example I want to just log Null pointer exceptions.

Comment: and it is another problem: I used to run command from root of my .jar file. when I call it from scheduler like c:/myfolder/my.jar it not compile with Exception of backLog that can not create log files. how I can handle this?

Comment: May be the directory mentioned in the logback doesn't exist, you can mention an absolute URL for logs. For filter NPE take a look at https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Answer (score 1):

You should add the application.properties file in your classpath and set logging properties there.

> If the only change you need to make to logging is to set the levels of
>   various loggers then you can do that in application.properties using
>   the "logging.level" prefix, e.g.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=C:\myapplication.log
```

> You can also set the location of a file to log to (in addition to the
>   console) using "logging.file".

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)

Comment: How I can put the file in root of jar file?

Comment: jar is a simple zip archive. By the way, you can add it to your classpath. Updated the answer.

Comment: It would like be logging.file=mylogfile.log and it will be save on JAR root. thank you your answer was useful.