# Big delay until SpringApplication.run() method completes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, postconstruct

I have the following class:

```
package org.edgexfoundry.pkg;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {
  public static ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    System.out.println("WELCOME!");
  }
```

and in another class of the same project I have:

```
@ImportResource("spring-config.xml")
public class BaseService {
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstructInitialize() {
        logger.debug("post construction initialization");
    }
}
```

where my `spring-config.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:*.properties" />

    <bean class="org.edgexfoundry.pkg.HeartBeat" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.edgexfoundry.pkg" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.edgexfoundry" />

</beans>
```

and the `HeartBeat` class:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class HeartBeat {

    private static final EdgeXLogger logger = EdgeXLoggerFactory.getEdgeXLogger(HeartBeat.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${heart.beat.time}")
    public void pulse() {
        logger.info("Beating...");
    }
}
```

When I run the project, I get the following output:

```
BySpringCGLIB$$1088c4ff] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2017, Dell, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
 ******************************************************************************/
WELCOME!

2019-04-02 12:50:24.574  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.edgexfoundry.pkg.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

and ***after a long time***, (about 8 minutes), I get the last line:

```
2019-04-02 12:57:04.611 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] org.edgexfoundry.pkg.BaseService         : post construction initialization
```

What is being done in the meantime? Why does the `@PostConstruct` method need so much time to run i.e. why does `SpringApplication.run()` method finish so late? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the logs are written in different log file, e.g. catalina.out?

Comment: @user7294900 where exactly do you mean? No file is produced in the folder where I am working... Also, according to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939849/spring-boot-default-log-location, spring boot outputs in the console...

Comment: Since you are using `@EnableDiscoveryClient` I think your app tries to connect to discovery server which might take time

Comment: @Ivan I have another project which is the same as this, but does not have this annotation. Still, it takes the same time...

Comment: Do you have any other annotations on top of `BaseService`? As it currently stands, I don't  see how your `BaseService` would be picked up by Spring as a bean.

Comment: @g00glen00b no, but I have another class which extends `BaseService` and has the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this problem locally when creating a Spring boot 2.1.3 project using a similar setup as yours.

Comment: The whole project is being deployed inside a VM created with `virt-install`... In my host machine I don't face this problem either, only inside the VM, but I didn't mention it because it has plenty of resources and I thought that it just happened to run fine in my host...

Comment: @Marievi Very difficult for others to troubleshoot then. The first thing that comes to mind is this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39636792/1915448. I can't guarantee that it's the same issue though. The first answer at least describes a similar situation as yours, where startup times could increase from 15 seconds to 6 minutes.

Comment: Reminds me of an issue with the JDK's PRNG provider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38944130/1770433

Comment: @mle Eventually I solved it with secure random. Thanks!

Comment: Shall I elaborate a little bit more about this pitfall and provide an answer for everyone here?

Comment: @mle of course!

Comment: @Marievi: elabrated a little more on my last comment and added it as answer, feel free to accept or upvote if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for a apparently slow startup is the default implementation of [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) which scans network interfaces to provide an additional source of system entropy.

One can avoid this by registering an own [`java.security.Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) or by using the [`SecureRandomSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandomSpi.html).

Amongst others there is also [this good introduction](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/thats-so-securerandom) in the topic of (fast) and secure pseudo random number generation in Java.