# How to print the logging directory of the spring-boot application in console while startup?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j, spring-logback

**How to enable the spring-boot application to print the logging directory while startup?**, like below example:

```
logging directory - /home/test/studentapp.log
```

Irrespective of any logging framework we use like `LOGBACK`, `Log4j2`, `Java Util logging` ..e.t.c in Spring, want to print the logging directory while startup.

Is there any property needs to be configured at application.properties to enable this?

> Edit:

For example, if I use the below logging `logback.xml` configuration, then I want to log the `logging directory` mentioned in the below configuration to the console at `application startup`, Like If you start kafka server It will give the location of the logging directories in the console at startup. In a similar way can we have this feature in spring?

```
<appender name="STUDENT_APP_LOG_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/home/test/studentapp.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{ dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS }] [ %5p ] [%thread] [ %logger ] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/home/test/archived/studentapp-%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring-boot default log location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939849/spring-boot-default-log-location)

Comment: Can you refer to output from apache kafka you mentioned? Have you tried probing the apache kafka source code to see how they do it? It is open source , can be found on github

Comment: No, I'm expecting a solution from spring configuration if present